# Git automatically add prefix to upstream branch name

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

It's pretty common-place when working in a repository with a lot of contributors to prefix all your branches with your name (or some other identifier). However, I don't like having to type my name every time I want to switch branches, so I usually leave it out of the local branch names.

So for example to push for the first time I usually use `git push -u origin HEAD:daniel/branch-name`, and when I am checking out a new branch I previously pushed from another machine I use `git checkout -b branch-name --track origin/daniel/branch-name`.

However, I have traded off typing my name when changing or manipulating branches for typing a lot more to set up a new branch. Is there some way of doing this automatically?

**Update:** As I was typing the question the answer occurred to me, so I've answered my own question, but I would still prefer a way of getting git to do this natively.

Like when I call `git push -u origin branch-name`, I want it to be equivalent to `git push -u origin branch-name:daniel/branch-name`. If I want something else I can specify that manually like `git push -u origin branch-name:branch-name`.

Similarly, when I call `git checkout new-branch` if new-branch doesn't exist and no remotes have a matching tracking branch, before giving up and returning an error, search for tracking branches which match `daniel/new-branch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using an alias. These are the aliases I came up with:

```
push-new=!"git push --set-upstream origin HEAD:daniel/$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's/^refs\\/heads\\///')"
checkout-new="!f() { git checkout -b $1 --track origin/daniel/$1; }; f"
```

Comment: Very unsatisfactory answer. :'(  It's also not for me, but for the people forgetting this all the time. -- Having a recieve-hook on the server could work, but we use GitHub, so can't do that. Will need another way (i.e.: a github action that complains).